# Have we ever seen Stamets and Detmer interact before?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-discovery

In ST:DIS 3x04, we see Detmer and Stamets getting into

> an argument, seemingly based upon general long-lasting disagreements between the two.

Detmer's behaviour felt like it came pretty much out of the blue to me. (Stamets' attitude in response to her behaviour not so much, although so far, it had seemed like there had been some character development going on since the days when he did usually display that attitude.)

Upon further pondering why the scene felt so unexpected to me, I now wonder: **Have we ever even seen Detmer and Stamets interact so far?**

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking: I thought it *was* resolved in the episode, as her reaction to the highly stressful situation. I was already relieved this was not explained as her implant catching a strain of *Control*, getting possessed by a spore ghost, or any such nonsense, and her becoming another "main character" who gets killed off before we learn anything about her, like with Airiam before.